# Reg Ex Facebook

Tags: regex, facebook-graph-api, screen-scraping, extract

I am trying to extract some information from facebook using Regex. Here is a link with an example:
https://graph.facebook.com/210989592315921
I was interested in what would the regular expression be in order to extract just the number of likes from this string.

I have tried for example this expression:

```
"likes":\s[0-9]$
```

Thank you in advance for any advice regarding this matter,
Mark

Comment: Why Regex and not `json_decode`?

Answer (score 0):

You should follow "@Hope I helped" comment and use a json parser. You can't be sure the text is going to be formatted always the same way:

Are you always going to have a single space between `:` and the number ?

By the way, here is the error you are looking for, your current regex matches a single figure, not a multiple digit number, you should use something like: `[0-9]+` and probably remove the `$` which is not correct in your example, as you have a comma after the number.